# onclick event does not work inside a function on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

This is my with inline onclick event. When written this way it works on both mobile devices as well as on PC:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/paper/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Limelight">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="">
   <span><a id="sp-login" style="cursor:pointer;">Login Here</a></span>
   <span> or <a id="sp-signup" style="cursor:pointer;">Create an Account</a></span>
   <input class="form-control" style="width:100%;display:none;" type="text" name="username" id="in-user" placeholder="Username" type="text"/>
   <input class="form-control" style="width:100%;display:none;" type="password" name="password" id="in-pass" placeholder="Password"/>
   <input class="form-control" style="width:100%;display:none;" type="email" name="email" id="in-email" placeholder="your@email.com (For Unique Key)"/>
   <button type="submit" name="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" style="display:none;width:210px;" id="in-login">Login</button>
   <button type="submit" name="submit" value="register" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" style="display:none;width:210px;" id="in-signup">Sign Up</button>
   </form>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#sp-login').on('click touchstart', function() {
         $('#in-user').show(); $('#in-pass').show(); $('#in-login').show(); $('#in-email').hide(); $('#in-signup').hide();
     }); 

       $('#sp-signup').on('click touchstart', function() {
         $('#in-user').show(); $('#in-email').show(); $('#in-signup').show(); $('#in-pass').show(); $('#in-login').hide();
     });
   });
   </script>
```

It works only on PC and not on mobile devices.

My jQuery version is 2.0.0. If it changes anything, I am using Bootstrap version 3.3.5.

Comment: There could be multiple reasons for something like this to happen. The two more probable are that the element doesn't exist when you assign the even handler (see Nitesh solution below); or maybe the id is not unique causing problems when you assign the handler (only the first one will trigger the actions). You'd need to provide more information (e.g. HTML code) to be able to determine the real cause

Comment: @Alvaro Will it still work on PC if 'element doesn't exist when you assign the even handler'?

Comment: The script is at the bottom of page just before the body tag.

Comment: It actually shouldn't, that's why I thought that you could have non-unique IDs. This question is missing key elements to determine the cause and solution. Check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I am adding more code so that you can see if there is any problem.

Comment: I have double checked all the IDs are unique.

Comment: I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/openscrp/) with the question code, opened it on Android, and it's working fine (hiding/showing fields depending on the link I click on)

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
$(document).on('touchstart click', '.myBtn', function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        if(event.handled !== true) {

            // Do your magic here.

            event.handled = true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: @Sujata Hulsurkar you should trythis out i think it would bemore generic way